# How to check if DVD-R is closed?

Tags: bash, dvd, burning, brasero, optical

When I burn a DVD with Brasero, it asks me whether I want to close the DVD after burn or leave it open to add files later.

How do I check whether a DVD is read-only or it's still writable? I am talking of course of DVD-R, not DVD-RW disks.

I am looking for some kind of console command to check whether the disk is closed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cdrskin` to get this information. Here are the two options that might be of use (from `man cdrskin`, emphasis mine):

> -minfo
>   Print information about the loaded media.  This  includes  media type, **writability state**, and a quite readable table of content.
>   -msinfo
>                 Retrieve **multi-session info** for preparing a follow-up session by
>                 option -C of  programs  mkisofs,  genisoimage,  or  xorriso  -as
>                 mkisofs.    Print   result  to  standard  output.   This  option
>                 redirects to stderr all message output except the one of  option
>                 --tell_media_space  and its own result string, which consists of
>                 two numbers.  The result string shall be  used  as  argument  of
>                 option -C with said programs.  It gives the start address of the
>                 most recent session and the predicted start address of the  next
>                 session  to  be appended. **The string is empty if the most recent
>                 session was not written with option -multi.**
>                 To have a chance for working on overwriteable media, this option
>                 has to be accompanied by option --grow_overwriteable_iso.

The manpage also has a list of examples, one of which shows the use of `-msinfo`:

> Get multi-session info for option -C of program mkisofs:
>
> ```bsh
> c_values=$(cdrskin dev=/dev/hdc -msinfo 2>/dev/null)
> mkisofs ... -C "$c_values" ...
> ```

To sum it up, you should be able to test for a CD/DVD to be appendable with the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(cdrskin -msinfo 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
  echo "Medium is appendable"
else
  echo "Medium is blank or closed"
fi
```

Oneliner version:

```bsh
[ "$(cdrskin -msinfo 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "appendable" || echo "blank or closed"
```

`cdrskin` takes the default drive which should be fine for nearly everyone. If it uses the wrong device, specify it explicitly with the option e.g. `dev=/dev/sr1`. If in doubt you can display information about a device with the option `-checkdrive`.

Comment: The test works for me with all three medium states. But the messages are wrong. Rather: "Medium is appendable" and "Medium is blank or closed". Blank is unused and writable. Appendable is written and still writable. Closed is written and not writable any more. Be aware that wodim happily reads -msinfo from closed DVD-R but not from blank ones.

Comment: Giving no device address is problematic if there is more than one optical
drive. libburn aquires all of them, groping each a little bit, in order 
to get a list of drives and their names. Then the first one is used and 
the others get released again. If you give a drive explicitely, then only 
that one is touched. On GNU/Linux /dev/sr0 is nowadays very surely the first drive.

To get a list of drives run: cdrskin --devices

Answer (score 1):

dessert's test exactly answers David's question.

But as said im my comment, we have three possible states for DVD-R.
To distinguish them all, one may use cdrskin option `-minfo`. 
(Note well: `-minfo` without the "s" of `-msinfo`.)

```
cdrskin dev=/dev/sr0 -minfo 2>/dev/null | grep '^disk status:'
```

This should yield 4 possible text results on standard output.

With a blank medium (unused and writable):

```
disk status:              empty
```

With an appendable medium (written and still writable):

```
disk status:              incomplete/appendable
```

With a closed medium (written and not writable any more):

```
disk status:              complete
```

As fourth possible result, if something goes wrong with accessing the
medium, no text at all will appear. In this case you should repeat the
run without `2>/dev/null | grep '^disk status:'` in order
to see all messages.

(I use `/dev/sr0` in the example, because `/dev/hdc`
is out of fashion as device name since at least kernel version 3.)

Comment: I just realized `cdrskin` is sapient enough to work fine without specifying a device at all – I guess it just uses the usual symlink `/dev/cdrom` or the like internally. I adapted my answer, got rid of all the (non-quoted) `/dev/` stuff and added a paragraph for the 1%.